# Why are bytes read from a file different between Java and VB.NET?

Tags: java, android, vb.net

I read data of a file.dat.

This is my code in VB.NET:

```vb
Dim data() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("F:\test.dat")
```

This is my code in android:

```java
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/data/test.dat";
File file = new File(fileName);
byte[] writeBuf= new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fis.read(writeBuf);
fis.close();
```

These are results: some bytes are different between Java and VB.NET

[image]

Why are the byte values are different between Java and VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at those values it appears that it's simply a signed/unsigned byte problem.

Signed Byte being -128 to 127 (used in your Java context) and Unsigned Byte being 0 to 255 (used in your .Net context).

Notice that where the numbers are different between the two contexts, if you add them, they sum to 256 (the maximum number of value for a byte regardless of signed/unsigned). (e.g. 154 + 102 = 256 and 217 + 39 = 256). So, the data is essentially the same, just represented differently given the supported datatype range.

Java doesn't have an unsigned byte.

Comment: In java, Have to convert signed to unsigned before convert bytes to text?

Comment: @DavidCross Please use the [edit] link below your answer if you want to add more information to the answer. I already edited it for you this time though.

Comment: You do not have to convert anything (not that it would be possible). Just convert to text using the right type like utf-8.